# Responding to request from Node.js using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I am trying to setup a Node.js script to use ECMAScript 6 promises. I am able to do the work I need in the Node script, which requires many fetches an external server (so is temporally expensive), but am unable to response to the client because the Promises construct causes a loss of reference to the Response (so I am guessing).

How can I propagate the Response object to the last Promises `then()` and reply to the request?

```
var http = require("http");
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
//...

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   //...
   var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (data) {
         buffer += data.toString();
      });
      res.on('end',function(d){
         //...stuff done with buffer...
         return resolve(0);
      });
  });

  req.end();
});

promise.then(function(i){

   //...expensive work on array...

   return Promise.all(myArrayData);
});

promise.then(function(result){
   //...want to reply to the request here, e.g.,...
   res.write(result);
});
```

Comment: If you route to the promise, the `req` object will be readily accessible

Comment: I'd probably resolve the http.request wrapping promise with the buffer response and then pass it around.

Comment: Mat, I answered the question but I'm not sure this is what you meant - if you just want to access _your_ local res variable, you can use closures and put `var response;` on the top and then `response = res` in the first line of the `http.request` callback.

Comment: RUJordan, how do I "route the promise"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to put the service call inside the route handler:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    myService().then(function(result){
        res.write(result);
        // res.end();
    });
});
```

Just like in synchronous code you call a function in the context you'd like it to execute:

```
var data = myService();
doSomethingWith(data);
```

Comment: (I'm unsure what this has to do with promises though).

Comment: This does not answer the question. I understand that it is a scoping issue but using the Promise constructs, I am unsure how to access the response object.

Comment: @Mat Your question is unclear. How would your working code look with callbacks? How would it look if it was synchronous?

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum, I would imagine that a subsequent callback could use the values returned from the prior callback but Promises seem to work a bit differently. @RUJordan mentioned (in the question comments) the approach would be to "route the promise" but promises are new to me (hence the question), so I wanted a way to effective use them to return the data to the client.